# Pairs of eigenvectors that are not multiple of each other

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following matrix

\begin{align}
J
&= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & \lambda a \\
a & \delta \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

For which I find two eigenvalues ($e_-$ and $e_+$):
\begin{align}
\det \left( J - e I \right) &= 0 \\
\det \left( 
\begin{bmatrix}
-e & \lambda a  \\
a & \delta -e \\
\end{bmatrix} \right) &= 0 \nonumber \\
e^2 - \delta e - \lambda a^2 &= 0 \nonumber \\
e_\pm = \frac{\delta \pm \sqrt{\delta^2 + 4 \lambda a^2}}{2}
\end{align}

Then I find the eigenvectors (denoted with v):
\begin{align}
\left( J - e_\pm I \right) v &= 0 \\
\begin{bmatrix}
- e_\pm & \lambda a \\
a & \delta - e_\pm \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
v^1 \\
v^2 \\
\end{bmatrix} &=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \nonumber \\
\begin{bmatrix}
- e_\pm v^1 + \lambda a v^2 \\
a v^1 + (\delta - e_\pm) v^2 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \nonumber
\end{align}
For the eigenvalue $e_+$:
\begin{align}
v^2 &= \frac{e_+}{\lambda a} v^1 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
v^1 &= \frac{e_+ - \delta}{a} v^2  
\end{align}
For the eigenvalue $e_-$:
\begin{align}
v^2 &= \frac{e_-}{\lambda a} v^1
\end{align}
\begin{align}
v^1 &= \frac{e_- - \delta}{a} v^2  
\end{align}
Therefore, setting $v^1 = 1$:
\begin{align}
\left\{ e_+ \ ; \ [ 1, \frac{e_+}{\lambda a}]^\top \right\} \quad \left\{ e_- \ ; \ [ 1, \frac{e_-}{\lambda a}]^\top \right\}
\end{align}
Setting $v^2 = 1$:
\begin{align}
\left\{ e_+ \ ; \ [ \frac{e_+ - \delta}{a}, 1]^\top \right\} \quad \left\{ e_- \ ; \ [ \frac{e_- - \delta}{a}, 1]^\top \right\}
\end{align}
Could you clarify why I obtain two pairs of eigenvectors that are not multiple of each other? How can the number of eigenvectors be greater than the dimension of the matrix?

Comment: I don't understand why you work with such complicated quantities. Your matrix boils down to this structure: $\pmatrix{0&\lambda a\\a&\delta}$

Comment: Not sure how this helps. The calculations do not seem to be the issue and are rather straightforward

Comment: Don't argue, when someone tries to help you. Just do it.

Comment: @NC520 in your quadratic equation there is a $\theta^2$ which becomes $\theta$ in the next formula. Anyhow $\det(J-e_\pm I)$ is zero, whence  $(J-e_\pm I)v=0$ has non trivial solutions.

Comment: Where exactly would the error be? Can you copy and paste the line? Everything seems fine

Comment: Sorry, maybe I miscomputed. Nevertheless, the systems $(J-e_{\pm}I)v=0$ must have non-trivial solutions, they provides the eigenvalues. Probably, following Jean Marie's suggestion, it is easier to find them.

Comment: You do understand that you have an infinite amount of eigenvectors per eigenvalue, right? You can pick *an* eigenvector, which spans a whole eigenspace associated with a given eigenvalue. Regardless, your calculation is wrong, very likely because you work with a very complicated expression. I strongly suggest that you reduce the offdiagonal entries with a constant, as others suggested.

Comment: Yes but the eigenvectors that I obtain are not multiple of each other. I am simplifying the calculations.

Comment: @JeanMarie I fixed the question as reccomended

Comment: Good! Now that you've reduced the question to its essentials, it's easy to see that (as user1551 notes) your eigenvectors are indeed scalar multiples of each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They **are** scalar multiples of each other:
$$
\left(\frac{e_+-\delta}{a},1\right)
=\frac{e_+-\delta}{a}\left(1,\frac{e_+}{\lambda a}\right).
$$
Note that $\dfrac{e_+-\delta}{a}\dfrac{e_+}{\lambda a}=1$ because $e_+$ is a root of the characteristic equation $x^2-\delta x-\lambda a^2=0$ of $J$.